# Java reverse server communication

Tags: java, networking

I have two machines.  One machine is a client and the other is a server running JBoss.  I have no trouble having the client make requests and the server respond to those requests.  However, for a new project that I need to do I have to reverse the roles.  I have to implement a push model, so the server will need to make requests from the client.  Specifically I need the server to be able to ask the client for files in a directory, copy files from the server to the client, and run programs on the client.  I'd like to do this without adding a psedo server on the client (a small daemon process).

Is there a good way to do this?

Thanks

EDIT:
So it would appear that I have to set up a server on the client machine to do what I need because I need to have the server push to the client while the client is not running the Java process (but the machine is on).  With that in mind, what's the lightest weight Java server?

Comment: you don't need to set up a server on the client machine. Just use JMS -- see my answer below for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason why you *don't* want to add a server process to the client ?

A simple implementation (to my mind) would be to embed an HTTP server like Jetty (which has a relatively small footprint) *within* your client. The client can then tell JBoss when it comes up (and where to find the client's Jetty) and then JBoss can just use HttpClient (or similar) to talk to the client.

If (as your comment suggests) you want to push to the machine whilst your client *isn't* running, then why not just install an `sshd` daemon and use `scp` via [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) ? You can [install Cygwin sshd](http://www.noah.org/ssh/cygwin-sshd.html) on Windows.

Comment: No reason, other than it seems like overkill to do processes which seem very simple on the surface, I guess they may not be.

Comment: If I were to go this route, which Java server would you recommend that I use?  The issue I have is that the server needs to push to the client when the client is not running (and the machine is just on), so with that in mind I'd have to create a whole webserver for the client that is always running.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable thing to do.  Can you recommend a good free Windows sshd like project?  My clients only run on Windows.

Comment: See the amended answer re Cygwin.

Comment: My issue is that the install has to be small.  The whole process is that the user will use a separate program to schedule the server to push files to the client.  The Java client program is installed and run using JNLP, so having the user download/install Cygwin is too much to ask for.

Answer (score 1):

> **I'd like to do this without adding a psedo server on the client (a small daemon process). Is there a good way to do this?**

No, not really. The client has to listen for incoming connections on some port in order for the server to initiate the communication.

There are other "push"-techniques that emulate push, such as "long polling" etc. The [Push technology Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) lists the following techniques for instance:

- HTTP server push
- Pushlet
- Long polling
- Flash XMLSocket relays

Answer (score 1):

> run programs on the client.....
>   without adding a psedo
>   server on the client

You cannot have the cake and eat it too. If you need to command another host to execute a program then the other host need to have some process that listens for the command. So the question boils down to finding the most lightweight or simplest solution.

The simplest solution would be to use shared folders for listing files and copying files and to use [RMI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html) for executing remote programs. More complex options involve developing a [Distributed Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_agent) using tools like [JADE](http://jade.tilab.com/) , using messaging middle-wares,say,JMS or using multi-casting tools like [jGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/).

PS: Developing a custom [SNMP agent](http://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/what_is_the_jvm_snmp) and manager might also work

Answer (score 0):

One way to simulate server push is [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) (Java Message Service) to push notifications from the server to its clients. JMS is a specialized protocol that allows you to efficiently push small messages between two or more applications. The scenario you describe is commonly implemented with JMS.

For example:

1. A client subscribes to a JMS topic on the JBoss server
2. The server sends a message to the JMS topic. The message payload could e.g. be command ID to list directory.
3. The client receives the JMS message, performs the command and calls service on server to return the result.

If you have multiple client applications and need to push notifications to individual client instances, then one solution is to have the server assign a unique ID to each client, which will be used to filter the JMS messages.

Comment: The issue that I have is that the files I need to transfer can be very large.  Can JMS accommodate large files?

Comment: You only use JMS to trigger the client into action. When the client receives a message, then you can have the client call e.g. a sessionless bean or a web service on the JBoss server to pass back large volumes of data

Comment: As in my other comments, my issue is that the Java client process is started by the user, however the server needs to push files to the client machine before the client process is started.

Comment: In that case, you can use JMS queues instead. The queue will persist the messages sent from the server. When the client launches and subscribes to the queue, it will receive the commands.

Comment: If you need to run the client in the background, without any user to start it, then you could consider using the Java Service Wrapper or Apache Commons Daemon. This way, your client application code would be able to run both as a background process or as a user launched app. Combined with JMS queues, you would never miss a command pushed from the server.